# Manage footer row heights

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a total footer for each of my groups. I want to manage the heights and I tried various solutions and none of them actually worked.

[image]

I tried the below gridOption, and it does not work:

```
 getRowHeight={(params) =>{
           if (params.node.footer) {
              return 80;
           }
           return 43;
        }
```

But when I increase the height of my group row -- W/C .... -- the footer height increases too.

Any idea how can I control group total rows? or if there is not, any idea how can I inject a row to each group?

Comment: why don't you use gri-layout of css ?

Comment: @Webman What that does? I tried to fix with css I couldn't

Comment: it for purpose to diagnostic your problem and better help you, that does exactly that ;). maybe you have relative values from one side and absolute values from another ? if it the case then the relative value grabs the maximum of space available, hence you can have weird distortion when you modify the space agencement

Comment: @Webman Is there any documentation for that? I just searched it and there is nothing related to this topic on AG docs

Comment: I don't know specifically AG-grid but what you do now is very doable with common CSS. You can always put some wrapper in your code and handle the case with a grid-layout. Have you read here : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aligned-grids/ ?

Comment: @Webman Thank you for your answer but customized CSS does not really help with some feature of the AG-Grid. Btw I appreciate your help